# Hair particles not following curve modifier :(

Tags: path

Happy Holidays everyone :)

I'm making a holiday special simulation this week but I can't do that if my garland is just a string.
[image]
The zig zag tube is the emitter which represents the string and the spiky things are the "leaves" of the garland, for lack of a better word.

Sad to say these leafy hair particles are just ignoring the curve modifier. :'(

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D
I also need my personal project finished before Dec. 31 :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95737/a-simple-way-to-make-a-wreath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of modifiers matters. In your case, Blender creates particles first and then blends the source mesh by the given curve. Just move the *Particle Modifier* down in your modifier stack.

Also check if you enabled *Use Modifier Stack* under *Particles > Emission* by accident.

[image]